# when restoring from a checkpoint, how can I change the data type of the parameters?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I have a pre-trained Tensorflow checkpoint, where the parameters are all of float32 data type.

**How can I load checkpoint parameters as float16? Or is there a way to modify data types of a checkpoint?**

Followings is my code snippet that tries to load float32 checkpoint into a float16 graph, and I got the type mismatch error.

```
import tensorflow as tf

A = tf.get_variable(name='foo', shape=[3, 3], dtype=tf.float32)
dense = tf.layers.dense(inputs=A, units=3)
varis = tf.trainable_variables(scope=None)
print(varis[1])  # <tf.Variable 'dense/kernel:0' shape=(3, 3) dtype=float32_ref>
assign = dict([(vari.name, vari) for vari in varis])
saver = tf.train.Saver(assign)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(dense))
    save_path = saver.save(sess, "tmp.ckpt")

tf.reset_default_graph()
A = tf.get_variable(name='foo', shape=[3, 3], dtype=tf.float16)
dense = tf.layers.dense(inputs=A, units=3)
varis = tf.trainable_variables(scope=None)
print(varis[1])  # <tf.Variable 'dense/kernel:0' shape=(3, 3) dtype=float16_ref>
assign = dict([(vari.name, vari) for vari in varis])
saver = tf.train.Saver(assign)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver.restore(sess, "tmp.ckpt")
    print(sess.run(dense))
    pass

# errors:
# tensor_name = dense/bias:0; expected dtype half does not equal original dtype float
# tensor_name = dense/kernel:0; expected dtype half does not equal original dtype float
# tensor_name = foo:0; expected dtype half does not equal original dtype float
```

Comment: I'm not sure if that's possible, but you can convert your `float16` data to `float32`.

Comment: I did this in an ugly way: construct your model with the dtype you want, create a session, then under this session you use `tf.train.NewCheckpointReader`, and load the variables one by one through the function [variable.load](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable#load) with the correct data type, then save a new checkpoint. Now you have a new checkpoint with the data type you want, and you can load it for your (new) model.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looking a bit into [how savers work](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.14.0/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py), seems you can redefine their construction through a `builder` object. You could for example have a builder that loads values as `tf.float32` and then casts them to the actual type of the variable:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.training.saver import BaseSaverBuilder

class CastFromFloat32SaverBuilder(BaseSaverBuilder):
  # Based on tensorflow.python.training.saver.BulkSaverBuilder.bulk_restore
  def bulk_restore(self, filename_tensor, saveables, preferred_shard,
                   restore_sequentially):
    from tensorflow.python.ops import io_ops
    restore_specs = []
    for saveable in saveables:
      for spec in saveable.specs:
        restore_specs.append((spec.name, spec.slice_spec, spec.dtype))
    names, slices, dtypes = zip(*restore_specs)
    restore_dtypes = [tf.float32 for _ in dtypes]
    with tf.device("cpu:0"):
      restored = io_ops.restore_v2(filename_tensor, names, slices, restore_dtypes)
      return [tf.cast(r, dt) for r, dt in zip(restored, dtypes)]
```

Note this assumes that all restored variables are `tf.float32`. You can adapt the builder appropriately for your use case if necessary, e.g. passing the source type or types in the constructor, etc. With this, you just need to use the above builder in the second saver to get your example to work:

```
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    A = tf.get_variable(name='foo', shape=[3, 3], dtype=tf.float32)
    dense = tf.layers.dense(inputs=A, units=3)
    varis = tf.trainable_variables(scope=None)
    assign = {vari.name: vari for vari in varis}
    saver = tf.train.Saver(assign)
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print('Value to save:')
    print(sess.run(dense))
    save_path = saver.save(sess, "ckpt/tmp.ckpt")

with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    A = tf.get_variable(name='foo', shape=[3, 3], dtype=tf.float16)
    dense = tf.layers.dense(inputs=A, units=3)
    varis = tf.trainable_variables(scope=None)
    assign = {vari.name: vari for vari in varis}
    saver = tf.train.Saver(assign, builder=CastFromFloat32SaverBuilder())
    saver.restore(sess, "ckpt/tmp.ckpt")
    print('Restored value:')
    print(sess.run(dense))
```

Output:

```
Value to save:
[[ 0.50589913  0.33701038 -0.11597633]
 [ 0.27372625  0.27724823  0.49825498]
 [ 1.0897961  -0.29577428 -0.9173869 ]]
Restored value:
[[ 0.506    0.337   -0.11597]
 [ 0.2737   0.2773   0.4983 ]
 [ 1.09    -0.296   -0.9175 ]]
```

Comment: thanks! actually that's pretty neat. the problem is when restoring using this method, the graph will no longer be the same because of the additional `cast` ops, any thoughts on how can I avoid that?

Comment: @dontloo Well the graph will be different anyway because the data types are different. If you want to keep the same exact graph structure and op types for some reason, the problem is tensors are restored through a `RestoreV2` op, which ends up in the C++ function [`RestoreTensorsV2`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v1.14.0/tensorflow/core/kernels/save_restore_tensor.cc#L317-L406). This will only produce their tensors in their original type. So either you cast, or you replace the restore op with some custom deserialization (complicated), which would make a different graph too.

Comment: @dontloo The alternative path would be to load the checkpoint in a different graph for example with this builder, save it again, then use it as usual in the actual graph...

Comment: right, that should be a viable solution, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

you can read source ckpt and modify it's data.

```
#include "tensorflow/core/util/tensor_bundle/tensor_bundle.h"

#include <random>
#include <vector>

#include "tensorflow/core/framework/tensor_util.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/types.pb.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/variant.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/variant_op_registry.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/versions.pb.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/lib/io/path.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/lib/io/table_builder.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/lib/strings/str_util.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/lib/strings/strcat.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/util/tensor_bundle/byte_swap.h"
    tensorflow::BundleReader reader(Env::Default(), model_path_prefix);
    std::vector<std::string> tensor_names;
    reader.Seek("");
    reader.Next();
    for (; reader.Valid(); reader.Next()) {
        tensor_names.emplace_back(reader.key());
    }
    tensorflow::BundleWriter writer(Env::Default(), new_model_path_prefix);   
    for (auto &tensor_name : tensor_names) {
            DataType dtype;
            TensorShape shape;        
            
            reader.LookupDtypeAndShape(tensor_name, &dtype, &shape);
            Tensor val(dtype, shape);
            Status bool_ret  = reader.Lookup(tensor_name, &val);
            std::cout << tensor_name << " " << val.DebugString() << std::endl;
            // modify dtype and shape. padding Tensor
            TensorSlice slice(new_shape.dims());
            writer.AddSlice(tensor_name, new_shape, slice, new_val);
        }
    }
    writer.Finish();
```