# Convert graph with dtype float64 to float32

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I have a graph but all tensor type are float64. In order to utilize GPU acceleration, float32 must be used. The only thing I have is a checkpoint file. Can I convert it from float64 to float32?

I think it can be done by parsing the graph structure and rebuild the graph manually. But this cost a lot of time. I am wondering if there are any tools which is proposed for this.

It is not the same problem as [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56557084). In their case, they has the code for graph building. In my case, i do not have that(unless i write it manually).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [when restoring from a checkpoint, how can I change the data type of the parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56557084/when-restoring-from-a-checkpoint-how-can-i-change-the-data-type-of-the-paramete)

Comment: @jdehesa Thanks for your reply. But it is not the same problem. In their case, they has the code for graph building. In my case, i do not have that(unless i write it manually).